# Creating a Self-Extracting Executable Using PHP

Tags: php, zip, executable

The self-extracting executable that I'm attempting to develop is an installer. An end-user will visit a site, then they will be prompted to register on the site and a download will be provided to them. That download is the self-extracting executable that will install the software on the end-user's computer along with a config file that will have the user's unique id in it. The software is a Windows Service so it will not be able to simply ask the user their username and password.

To be able to insert the registered user's unique id into the installer, I would have to generate the installer on the fly. After researching and using my own experience, I decided that a self-extracting executable would be the best option. The question I have now is how can I generate one using PHP? After researching this problem, I found that the most common solution was to install a executable that could create self-extracting executables on the server machine and then invoke it from PHP. However, executing a executable is not possible with my web host, so this is not a viable solution.

Comment: this looks fishy.. what do you want to do?

Comment: Haha, it does sound a little fishy. We're making a service that will automatically download a list of files to the end-user's computer, so we need a client program to view a user-specific xml file on our website that contains a list of downloads that the client (Windows Service) will download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, executing a executable is not possible with my web host, so this is not a viable solution.

I think in that case, you will need to switch to a web host that lets you do this (or rent a dedicated or virtual server). You can create ZIP files from within PHP when the necessary libraries are installed, but that is about it. Producing Self-extracting executables is not on the menu.

If that is not an option, you would have to find a way to pre-produce the self-extracting executable and inject the user ID into it afterwards. That is surely possible, but I expect you would have to build a custom self-extractor for this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't decide what web host we use.

Comment: @Dylan then there probably is no way, unless you find a way to pre-produce the self-extracting executable and inject the user ID into it afterwards

Comment: @Pekka you gave me an idea. From what I know, PHP is capable of editing binary files, so, maybe I can replace a placeholder in a pre-produced self-extracting exe with the binary equivalent of the user's unique id. To be honest, I'm not sure if this will work but I will look into it. Thanks Pekka.

Comment: @Dylan: I was just about to answer something similar when I read this comment. You can even deliver the download through a php script which passes the binary data through, except for the region where the user info goes. you'll need to pad the data to be sure every one has the same number of bytes, and watch out for checksums built into the compression format.

Comment: In the case of editing a binary file, it is important that the replaced value has the same size (in bits or bytes).

Comment: @grossvogel Thanks for pointing out the padding of the data and the checksums. Those could be a real pain. I could solve the padding problem by making the placeholder in the pre-produced archive larger than any unique id that would be generated and filling in the remaining bytes of the placeholder with a character such as '-' that is not used in the unique id. Then, in the client program, I could ignore all of the '-'s. The checksum problem could be solved by choosing a compression format without checksums :D. Thanks again grossvogel and Pekka.

Comment: @Dylan good luck! It would be interesting to hear how this worked out.  In case you get stuck and can afford the huge size, remember the zip format has a "0" compression rate that (IIRC) just concatenates uncompressed files.

Comment: Wish I could find the source page again, but I did find a simple .exe stub which you could simply prepend to a .zip file and generate a basic windows self-extracting zip, and could do this from any system that could concatenation files. Came in very handy for one project I did.

Comment: @Dylan this is to notify you of @Marc's comment, that might be a good lead

Comment: Ah... brainfart. Here it is: http://www.info-zip.org   The UnzipSFX portion is the .exe stub.

Answer (score 0):

A self-extracting archive is just an extractor with archive data appended. The extractor program opens itself, finds the offset of the data and extracts. There might be a trailer record to help find the offset.

You can append files easily in PHP: both an archive with your program and the user data. But you need to write a custom extractor that will be aware of this format.

Comment: Good idea. I might try this as well because, for sure, PHP does contain  functions to create/edit archives and to append files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible.. The most you could do is use PHP to dynamically grab the files required surely?

Anyway, perhaps your application could access the internet to grab the files it needs periodically?

Or, you could reference an external PHP file in your program like `/data.php?userid=1222&token=9999` which should be fairly secure.

Comment: the problem is how to get the userid

Comment: Ah, I see, I guess I misread the question. I'll have to give this some though.